# How to retrive all the children from nested database in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am able to retrieve the child if it is present as data/ a, data/b. But I want to retrieve all the data which are present as data/key1/a, data/key1/b, data/key2/a, data/key2/b.

Now I am using the code as,

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("notifications");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
var uid = snap.child("uid").val();
});
```

This is giving me the data present in - notifications/key1/uid, notifications/key2/uid.

My database is made as notifications/key1/key1timestamp/uid, notifications/key2/key2timestamp/uid.

How do I edit my code to access that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var ref1 = db.ref("notifications");

ref1.on("value", (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=> {
    childSnapshot.forEach((childrenSnapshot)=>{
      let userId = childrenSnapshot.val().uid;
    });
});
```

Assuming you have this database:

```
notifications
       key1
         key1timestamp
                 uid: id_here
        key2
          key2timestamp
                 uid:id_here
```

Since the snapshot is at `notifications` then loop twice to be able to retrieve the nested children